# Change to jdk 7 in eclipse(sts)

Tags: eclipse, sts-springsourcetoolsuite, java-7

How do I switch project from JDK 6 to 7, I know I am not using it because switch doesn't accept String.

In build path I have jre 7 in compiler settings I have 1.7 , everywhere and it still doesn't work. I use Spring Tool Suite(Eclipse based) latest version which officially supports Java 7.

And in project facets I also have 1.7. Why it has to be so bloody difficult.

And in .ini I have perfectly correct C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0\bin\javaw.exe
-startup

And I am sure my IDE supports 7 because whenever I create new project I have not syntax errors with String switch statement.

And my JAVA HOME set to JDK 1.7 :-)

UPDATE: The problem only happens with projects of Spring nature.

UPDATE 2: Happens with template Spring MVC project, Spring Hibernate template apparently works with Java 7.

Totally confused.

Answer (score 2):

When I start a new Java project  in Eclipse Indigo, eclipse tells me that the compiler compliance level 1.7 is not supported:

[image]

It is not possible to change that from inside eclipse, the properties dialog shows that:

[image]

So as a result, it is not possible to use the new switch statement with Strings in it:

[image]

See the ["Eclipse Forums Post"](http://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/m/717585/) for more information about the topic. It seems that it will come only with the next eclipse version.

Comment: If you update to Eclipse 3.7.1, all JDK7 features are supported.

Comment: it is not case with me, in that dropdown menu I have 1.7 and whenever I create new simple java project I can use switch statements with String easily. It is only with previously imported projects of spring nature.

Answer (score 1):

In window / preferences / Installed JREs you need to have the JDK1.7 as the default set up. Additionally in Project / Properties Java Compiler it should be also set (or disable the project specific settings)

**UPDATE :**

In my .settings folder there is a file called org.eclipse.wst.common.project.facet.core.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<faceted-project>
  <fixed facet="wst.jsdt.web"/>
  <installed facet="java" version="1.6"/>
  <installed facet="jst.web" version="2.4"/>
  <installed facet="wst.jsdt.web" version="1.0"/>
</faceted-project>
```

and contains some rather suspicious values. Not sure it matters, but worth trying to close the project change it then reopen the project. If that doesnt help then search for the string 1.6 in all files in your project

Comment: I have that , I told already... The problem with imported project which used 6.

Comment: I don't really know whats happening it seems that spring projects are the ones that do not want to work with java 7, any other simple java projects run perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

Compare `.classpath` and `.project` files between your simple Java projects and Spring projects. Sometimes the *Nature* or other project setting can be set differently.

Comment: I left imported project and created new from spring template. It has the same problem as the imported. However no problems with simple java projects, maven though is used automatically for spring projects can that be the cause? (I compared files , nothing extraordinary apart from some entries swaped with maven)

Comment: However no problems in there: <java-version>1.7</java-version>